# Buffered writes to stdout in node.js

Tags: node.js

In node.js the `process.stdout` stream is documented to behave "synchronously" which, among other things, means that *every call to `stdout.write`* causes an immediate `write` system call -- there's no buffering.  For instance

```
import { stdout } from 'process';

for (let i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
    stdout.write(`line ${i}\n`);
}
stdout.end();
```

makes 1000 `write` system calls.  This is Not What You Want when you are writing a traditional Unix data-emitting utility.  It's possible to bypass `process.stdout` and create a separate Writable stream that sinks to file descriptor 1, e.g.

```
import { stdout } from 'process';
import { createWriteStream } from 'fs';
let ostream = createWriteStream("/ignored", { fd: stdout.fd });
for (let i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
    ostream.write(`line ${i}\n`);
}
ostream.end();
```

makes just one system call.  However, bypasses like this are dangerous -- after the `ostream.end` call, file descriptor 1 is closed but the `process.stdout` object does not know that.

Is there an official way to get buffered output when using `process.stdout`?  Ideal in my book would be something like C's [`setvbuf`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html).

Comment: Does this npm package [write-buffer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/write-buffer) suit your need?

Comment: I saw write-buffer too and think it could be part of a solution, but it doesn't seem to be exactly the solution out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

## Use `process.stdout.cork()`

> The writable.cork() method forces all written data to be buffered in memory. The buffered data will be flushed when either the stream.uncork() or stream.end() methods are called.

Note: this will cork also `console.log()`.

```
process.stdout.cork();
for (let i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
    process.stdout.write(`line ${i}\n`);
}
process.stdout.uncork();
```

Or, if you want to flush the buffer every time the event loop is reached, you can override `write()`:

```
const { stdout } = process;
const { write } = stdout;

stdout.write = function() {
  if (this.writableCorked == 0) {
    this.cork();
    process.nextTick(() => this.uncork());
  }
  write.apply(this, arguments);
}

for (let i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
  process.stdout.write(`line ${i}\n`);
}
```

If you are worried about the buffer getting to big, you might want to also check `stdout.writableNeedDrain`.

`strace -f -c -e trace=write,writev` results:

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000006           1         4           write
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           writev
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000006                     5           total
```

Tested using node v16.13.2

Comment: This would take me from "buffer nothing" to "buffer the _entire output_ and write it all at once" which is too far in the other direction, especially when the size of the output is unpredictable.

Comment: Yes it does, and it is not ideal. You asked for the official way to get buffered output when using `process.stdout` and I answered that,

Comment: @zwol - I've updated the answer to give you another option. I hope this is helping.

Answer (score 0):

You can call .end() on stdout too. I'm not sure if this makes it safer.

```
import { promisify } from 'util';
import stream from 'stream';
import { stdout } from 'process';
import { createWriteStream } from 'fs';

const finished = promisify(stream.finished);

let ostream = createWriteStream("/ignored", { fd: stdout.fd });
for (let i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
    ostream.write(`line ${i}\n`);
}
ostream.end();

await finished(ostream).then(()=> {
  console.log('Not quite done.');
  stdout.end()
  console.log('Not gonna see this.');
});
```

EDIT: I just read in the [Node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#a-note-on-process-io) that on POSIX systems, if you use pipes to send data to stdout, that it is async. So the following code should work:

```
import { stdout } from 'process';
import { Readable } from 'stream';
const data = new Readable()

data._read = () => {};

data.pipe(stdout);

for (let i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
  data.push(`line ${i}\n`);
}
```

Comment: Re your edit, I don't see where it says "if you use pipes to send data to stdout, then it is async" in the docs you linked, and a quick test indicates that your second program does the same 1000 write calls that my first program does.  I didn't know you could use `push` on a `Readable`, though, so this is still helpful, thanks.

Comment: Bullet 2 says that stdout writes are async when using pipes and sockets. I don't know for sure that it would be less calls to the system, but because it's async (according to the docs), it seems like it would be the same as using a writable stream to the stdout file descriptor. This is all at a level lower than I typically deal with, so I'm unfamiliar how to test to be sure. Super interesting question.

Comment: Re how to test, for example `strace -f -c -e trace=write,writev node test.mjs` where `test.mjs` contains any of the test programs we've been kicking around.

Answer (score 0):

After giving this a bunch more thought, the ideal way to set up to use `process.stdout` safely and efficiently for bulk data output would be to `dup`  the OS-level `STDOUT_FILENO`, wrap a normal `fs.WriteStream` around the duplicate, and then `dup2` `STDERR_FILENO` over `STDOUT_FILENO`, which would make all of the global console object's methods, and `process.stdout`, write to stderr instead of stdout.  (As far as I can tell there is no other way to do that.)  The code generating the bulk data would then write to the normal WriteStream instead of to process.stdout.

Or, in code:

```
import * as fs from "fs/promises";
import process from "process";
async function prepare_buffered_stdout(options) {
    options ??= {};
    const stdout_copy = await fs.dup(process.stdout.fd);
    await fs.dup2(process.stderr.fd, process.stdout.fd);
    return fs.fdopen(stdout_copy, "w").createWriteStream(options);
}
```

There is, unfortunately, the minor problem that the functions `fs.dup`, `fs.dup2`, and `fs.fdopen` do not exist.  I have filed a [feature request for them to be added](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/41733).